# Unicorn 3.3.1 and Rack 1.1.0 issues?

Tags: ruby, unicorn, gem, ruby-rack

I'm upgrading from the Ruby Enterprise Edition 1.8.6 to the latest 1.8.7 version with Unicorn to facilitate an upgrade to Rails 2.3.10, and am running into some issues. Should I uninstall the older versions of these gems?

Here's the log messages:

I'm upgrading from the Ruby Enterprise Edition 1.8.6 to the latest 1.8.7 version with Unicorn to facilitate an upgrade to Rails 2.3.10, and am running into some issues. Should I uninstall the older versions of these gems?

```
I, [2011-02-02T22:06:16.328076 #30672]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=3
I, [2011-02-02T22:06:16.333137 #30672]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/srv/ree/bin/unicorn_rails must be run inside RAILS_ROOT: #<Gem::LoadError: can't activate rack (~> 1.1.0, runtime) for ["actionpack-2.3.10", "rails-2.3.10"], already activated rack-1.2.1 for ["unicorn-3.3.1"]>
I, [2011-02-02T22:07:12.259436 #30701]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=3
I, [2011-02-02T22:07:12.259952 #30701]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/srv/ree/bin/unicorn_rails must be run inside RAILS_ROOT: #<Gem::LoadError: can't activate rack (~> 1.1.0, runtime) for ["actionpack-2.3.10", "rails-2.3.10"], already activated rack-1.2.1 for ["unicorn-3.3.1"]>
I, [2011-02-02T22:09:27.787177 #30772]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=3
I, [2011-02-02T22:09:27.787691 #30772]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/srv/ree/bin/unicorn_rails must be run inside RAILS_ROOT: #<Gem::LoadError: can't activate rack (~> 1.1.0, runtime) for ["actionpack-2.3.10", "rails-2.3.10"], already activated rack-1.2.1 for ["unicorn-3.3.1"]>
I, [2011-02-02T22:10:44.175407 #30846]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=3
I, [2011-02-02T22:10:44.175928 #30846]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/srv/ree/bin/unicorn_rails must be run inside RAILS_ROOT: #<Gem::LoadError: can't activate rack (~> 1.1.0, runtime) for ["actionpack-2.3.10", "rails-2.3.10"], already activated rack-1.2.1 for ["unicorn-3.3.1"]>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this problem as well.  We were using Bundler and it didn't seem to help.  A certain gem was wanting to use Rack 1.1.0 but unicorn wasn't having it.  I don't think rvm with gemsets would help because two different gems are demanding two different versions of rack.

Ultimately I ended up with a production server running:

```
Rails 2.3.10
Ruby Enterprise Edition 1.8.7
Bundler 1.0.10
Unicorn 3.1.0
Rack 1.1.0
```

You must uninstall Rack 1.2.1.  I am also using `unicorn_rails` which wraps my rails app in rack.  I'm not sure if this is necessary but I couldn't get my rails routes working correctly with a rack specific app (dragonfly).

Also, you need to run that command from the root of your rails directory (unless you specify a working_directory in the config).  I recommend using Brandon Tilley's guide to [serving Rails Apps with RVM, Nginx, and Unicorn](http://brandontilley.com/2011/01/29/serving-rails-apps-with-rvm-nginx-unicorn-and-upstart.html) although I couldn't get upstart to work correctly.  I ended up making my own /etc/init.d/unicorn_test_app script which basically just runs:

```
rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm \
/usr/local/bin/rvm-shell "ree-1.8.7-2011.03@test_app_rails2" -c \
"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@test_app_rails2/bin/unicorn_rails \
-D -E production -c /var/www/test_app/config/unicorn.rb"
```

and then kills the process with specific signals.  It's pretty nice once you get it all working because you can have zero down time deploys (aside migrations).

Only thing I don't like about my script: it's gemset specific.

Answer (score 0):

I see three ways to solve the problem:

- Use bundler
  (http://gembundler.com/rails23.html)
- Use rvm with gemsets
  (http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/)
- Use old rack (# gem uni rack -v
  '=1.2.1'; gem in rack -v '=1.1.0')